# How to enable xdebug log in Laravel sail?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, xdebug

I am trying to enable xdebug log in Laravel 8, using the sail package for docker.

According to [xDebugs docs](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings) log will appear automatically when set the `xdebug.log` to a value.

This is what I tried:

1. Publish sail's files using `sail artisan sail:publish`
2. This created `/docker/7.4`, `/docker/8.0`, `/docker/8.1`
3. With `sail php -v` I saw that I am using php 8.0.12
4. Now I added `xdebug.log =/var/www/html/storage/app` to `docker/8.0/php.ini`
5. I run `sail build --no-cache` and restart container. This takes about 8 minutes.

Unfortunately, checking phpinfo() shows that `xdebug.log` has no value:
[image]

According to my docker file, the `php.ini` should have been copied:
`COPY php.ini /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini` so I wanted to try to read the file. To do this, I tried the following:

1. Log into container using `sail shell`
2. Go to `cd /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/`
3. Read file using `cat 99-sail.ini`

That is the content:

```
[PHP]
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
variables_order = EGPCS

# Extensions...
extension=swoole.so

# Zend Extensions...
zend_extension=xdebug.so
```

However in `/docker/8.0/php.ini` I have only this:

```
[PHP]
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
variables_order = EGPCS
xdebug.log =/var/www/html/storage/app
```

Why is that? I also would like to try to just edit the file directly, but `vim` is not known. Also the command `sudo` is not known, although image is  ubuntu:21.04. I tried to install vim, but I am missing access rights.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> `COPY php.ini /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini`

You can just add Xdebug configuration in the `php.ini` file that gets copied. But if you update it, then you need to rebuild/restart your container.

Comment: That is what I tried. I added the value to `docker/8.0/php.ini` but it was not copied. Instead the 99-sail.ini looks very different from any php.ini file inside the docker/ folder

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this Laravel app used its own dockerfile. I forgot to check `docker-compose.yml`. Inside `laravel.test` was build that pointed to a different file. Thats why the php.ini inside docker file was not copied.

Also I had to use a path to an actual log file and put it in quotations like this:

```
xdebug.log ="/var/www/html/storage/app/xdebug.log"
```